# Why code is not printing anything as output?

Tags: c, eof

After pressing Ctrl+D, i am expecting this code to print array, but its doing nothing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int k,i=0,a;
    int b[10];
    while(scanf("%d",&a)!=EOF){
        if(a>(a/4+a/3+a/2))
        b[i]=a;
        else
        b[i]=(a/4+a/3+a/2);
        i++;
    }
    for(k=0;k<=i;k++){
        printf("%d\n",b[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but works for me. What is the exact sequence you enter before ctrl d?

Comment: What are you compiling your code with?

Comment: what operating system are you using ? What terminal ?

Comment: In case this doesn't work on your machine, I recommend to try out such examples on www.nitrous.io (no affiliation from my side). It works fine for me under linux.

Comment: Post what you are typing.  The sequence of keys immediately before Ctrl-D is important.

Comment: @Kevin: `"%d"` skips over and ignores whitespace...

Comment: @SanderDeDycker : Windows 8

Comment: @chux : any normal input like 2 3 4. After that, when i press ctrl-D, nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong key combination to generate an EOF on your operating system (Windows 8). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is common on unix-like systems, but Windows systems generally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Note that you might have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice if you're not on an empty line (once to flush the current line of input, and once to generate the EOF).

Answer (score 1):

Best guess -- you're entering something that is not a number, so `scanf` returns 0 and your program enters an infinite loop.  As you don't show your input, it's impossible to tell.

If you want it to stop on a non-number input, change the loop to `while(scanf("%d",&a) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

you should check the documentation for scanf's return value... it returns the number of items scanned, 0, 1, 2, etc... not EOF

Comment: Actually, [it returns *either*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). EOF is returned if a read error occurred, such as actually *being* at EOF and are still trying to read data.