# EOF in C doesnt work

Tags: c, eof

I have a problem with reading chars from input. Program should end when I press ENTER or CTRL + Z.

Example input:
LoreCTRL+Z .... is cycling
but when I press CTRL+Z and there is no text before it, it works.
Could anybody help me? Thanks

```
int intFromConsole = getchar();
if((intFromConsole == EOF) || (intFromConsole == '\n')){
    //code
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16786922/5647037) can help you with CTRL+Z problem. what is the other issue you're having?

Comment: You may find the note in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22719565/1322972) interesting as well.

Comment: what is "cycling"?

Answer (score 2):

That is probably not related to your program but to the terminal subsystem (in the kernel) which is responsible for that behaviour.

Your terminal is usually in "line discipline" state. Notice that your program doesn't receive the "Lore" directly but only when you press return. (the input is line-buffered).

Another catch, you usually shouldn't expect Ctrl+Z (ASCII 26) as input since that is intercepted by the terminal subsystem in most terminal states, which pauses your program and sends it to the background.

You can get more interesting information from Linus Akesson's article [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Answer (score 1):

The function `getchar()` uses buffered input. In Windows, `Ctrl-Z` is only recognised when it follows a `newline` entry. But in Windows, you might have `conio.h` available to you in the library. If so, here is something for you to experiment with. It accepts each keystroke immediately, and prints the value in hex. It exits when `Ctrl-Z` is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ENDOF 0x1A      // Ctrl-Z

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = _getch();
        printf("%02X\n", ch);
    } while(ch != ENDOF);
}
```

Program input

```
1234<Ctrl-Z>
```

Program output

```
31
32
33
34
1A
```

Answer (score 0):

> Program should end when I press ENTER or CTRL + Z.

If above is what you want, you could do something like :

```
int main(void)
{
        char ch;

        do
        {
                while(ch!='\n')
                        getchar(); // waste the buffer

                /* Do the useful stuff here */

                ch=getchar();
        }while(ch!=EOF && ch!='\n'); 

        /* Note the logical operator is && . It says if the key pressed
         * is neither Enter nor Ctrl -Z do some stuff.
         * The program exits only when you directly press Enter key or
         * Ctrl -Z / Ctrl -D. Okay ! Now it is time to take a nice walk
         * thru the Grand Central Park.
         */ 

        return 0;
}
```

For Linux machines Ctrl-Z generates the SIGSTOP which cannot be trapped. So to signal EOF you should instead use Ctrl-D.

**References :**

[Linux Signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)